# Computing expected value of loss function for linear regression with dropout

Tags: probability, optimization, machine-learning

Consider a linear regression problem with input data $X\in R^{n\times d}$, weights $w\in R^{d\times 1}$ and targets $y\in R^{n\times 1}$.
Suppose that dropout is applied to the input (with probability $1-p$ of dropping the unit i.e. setting it to 0).
Let $R\in R^{n\times d}$ be the dropout mask such that $ R_{ij}\sim\text{Bern}(p)$ is sampled i.i.d. from the Bernoulli distribution.

For a squared error loss function with dropout, we then have:
$$L(w)=||y-(X\odot R) w||^2$$
Here $\odot$ means elementwise multiplication between two matrices

Let $\Gamma$ be a diagonal matrix with $\Gamma_{ii}=(X^\top X)_{ii}^{1/2}$.
Show that the $\textit{expectation (over $ R$)}$ of the loss function can be rewritten as $ E[L(w)]=|| y-pXw||^2+p(1-p)||\Gamma w||^2$.

So I got the following:

$$E[L(w)] = E[\| y- (X \odot R) w\|^2]
        = E[(y^T-w^T(X \odot R)^T)(y-(X \odot R)w)]\\
        =E[y^Ty-2\sum_{ij}y_iw_jX_{ij}p-2\sum_{ij}y_iw_jX_{ij}p+\sum_{ijk} w_i w_j X_{ki} X_{kj} p^2] = || y-pXw||^2$$

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M = X \odot R$, and we know that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[M] = pX, \quad \text{var}~(M)=p(1-p)\Gamma^2.
\end{equation}
Thus 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[L(w)] &=E[(y^T-w^TM^T)(y-Mw)] = y^Ty - 2y^T\mathbb{E}[M]w +w^T\mathbb{E}[MM^T]w \\
&= y^Ty - 2y^T p Xw + p^2w^TX^TXw + p(1-p)w^T\Gamma^2w \\
&= \|y-pXw\|^2 + p(1-p) \|\Gamma w\|^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't understand how you get from first line to second line: namely, why is there $p(1-p)w^T\Gamma^2w$ term?

Comment: This is the variance of $M$. you can view $M$ as a random vector. And then compute the variance of it. Obviously, each component of $M$ is independent, so it is a diagonal matrix, i.e. $p(1-p)\Gamma^2$.

Comment: ok thank you sir, can you also please explain why we need to calculate the variance as the question asks to find the expected value of the loss function?

Comment: In general, we compute the expectation of the square of random variance, thus we need second central moment. For details, to compute $\mathbb{E}[M^TM]$, it equals to $\mathbb{E}[M^TM] = \operatorname{var} [M] + (\mathbb{E}[M])^2$

Comment: I don't understand the last part. Can you derive it?

Comment: According to the equation for [covariance matrix] [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix]

Comment: This link may be more useful, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance.

Comment: @Ze-NanLi can you explain in more depth the variance of $M$. or direct me to resources, please? Thanks