# Expectation of the product of two matrices

Tags: probability, expected-value, machine-learning, variance

I recently viewed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3573086/179660) and I decided it to give it a try. I got stuck in the computation of a certain expectation and variance. Summarizing the problem, this is the issue:

> Let $X\in R^{n\times d}$ be a data matrix, $R\in R^{n\times d}$ a
> matrix such that $ R_{ij}\sim\text{Bern}(p)$ is sampled i.i.d. from
> the Bernoulli distribution, $M=X\odot R$ the element-wise product
> of the previous two matrices, and $\Gamma$ be a diagonal matrix with
> $\Gamma_{ii}=(X^\top X)_{ii}^{1/2}$.
>
> Show that $E[M]=pX$, and $var(M)=p(1-p)\Gamma²$

I first went considering both the columns of $X$ and $R$ as independent vectors. Using a specific example where both $X$ and $R$ have three columns, i.e. $X=[A\ B\ C]^T$, and $R=[\alpha\ \beta\ \delta]^T$, we have that $M=[\alpha A\ \beta B\ \delta C]^T$. Taking the expectation of this:
$$E[M]=
\begin{bmatrix} 
E[\alpha A] \\
E[\beta B]\\
E[\delta C] \\
\end{bmatrix} \stackrel{\star}{=} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
E[\alpha]E[A] \\
E[\beta]E[B]\\
E[\delta]E[C] \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
pE[A] \\
pE[B]\\
pE[C] \\
\end{bmatrix}=pE[X]
$$

where I used that $\star$ the variables are independent.

It doesn't look like the answer is correct and I am not sure what I am misunderstanding. For the variance, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Either your $X$ is deterministic, and in this case your answer can not be $\mathbb{E}[X]$ at the end. Or your $X$ is random, and in this case there is no hope that $\mathbb{E}[M]$ gives you something depending on $X$ without any expectation. Can you explain a bit more what you mean by data matrix ? Is there randomness involved ?

Comment: You are fantastically correct @Gâteau-Gallois, and I was writing my own answer as you commented. I just realised what is the answer. X is taken as a matrix of constants whereas $R\sim Bern(p)$. That's why $E[M]=pX$. However I need to finish the variance:
$$
\begin{align}
var(M)&=E[(M-E(M)²]=E[M²-2ME[M]+E²[M]]=\\
&=E[M^2]-2E^2[M]+E²[M]=E[M^2]-E^2[M]=\\
&=E[X^TX]-p²X^TX=...?
\end{align}$$

Comment: It is not super clear to me what should be the form of the covariant matrix of a random matrix (because this is what you essentially look at). 
On the other hand you're looking at the element-wise product, so isn't the covariance matrix you're looking for just given by the matrix where the component (i,j) is given by the covariance of $X_{ij} R_{ij}$ ? In which case the formula should be straightforward. Otherwise you need to clarify what you mean by covariance matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised what is the answer (and also thanks to the reflection questions of [@Gateau-Gallois](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/393828/g%C3%A2teau-gallois)).

1. Mean: $X$ is taken as a matrix of constants whereas $R\sim Bern(p)$. That's why $E[M]=pX$.
2. Variance: Following a similar argument, one can see then that the covariance matrix is:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   var(M_{ij})&=var(X_{ij}R_{ij})\stackrel{\star}{=}X_{ij}^2var(R_{ij})
   \end{align}$$
   where $\star$ is the same assumption as in the question and the fact that $var(aX)=a^2var(X)$. The expression results in 0 if $i\neq j$ since $R_{ij}$ are i.i.d. and otherwise is $X^2_{ii}var(R_{ii})=X^2_{ii}p(1-p)$. Taking, then, the matrix form:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   var(M)=p(1-p)(X^TX)_{ii}\stackrel{\star^2}{=}p(1-p)\Gamma^2
   \end{align}
   $$
   where $\star^2$ is the definition $\Gamma=(X^TX)_{ii}^{1/2}$stated in the question.